# Adding a gap in between optgroups

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner web developer that has a quick and simple question. I'm trying to figure out the best way to add a gap/space between two optgroups within a single select tag. One solution I found was adding a third, empty optgroup in between them, but am wondering if there is a cleaner approach. I appreciate the help!

Here's an example of how I have it currently working:

```
<select name="selectionMenu" id="selectionMenu">

    <optgroup label="Section1"></optgroup>

    <optgroup></optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Section2"></optgroup>

</select>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then add some code to your question in a functional snippet.

Comment: Have you considered CSS? You've added a `css` tag so I guess you're aware of this technology.

Comment: Add custom css : optgroup{margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}

Comment: I've tried adding CSS. It doesn't seem to apply within a select dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the disabled attribute for an empty optgroup or option so it doesn't add a blank entry that the user can select:

```
<optgroup disabled="disabled"></optgroup>
```

or

```
<optgroup>
<option disabled="disabled"></option>
</optgroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a <`div style="height:5px;"></div>` between the option groups to apply a space between them. Adjust the height to your liking. I use this method sometimes to provide a gap between my menu bar across my page and the starting of the text below. It should work in your scenario.